# Dynamically list and click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make list (like ng-repeat in angularjs) and click on any of item in list, call function with passed data of the selected item

I make list with `$.ajax` call and `$.each`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var inHTML = "";

    $.ajax({
        url:        'http://some.some',
        dataType:   "json",
        success:    function(data){
            $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><th><h5 style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 15px;">' + "Events" + '</h5></th></tr>');
            $.each(data.videos, function(key, value){

                $("#dynamicTable").append('<table><tr><td class="aktivniItem backgroundIdKlupa_izbornik_td" style="color: white">'+ moment(value.time).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') +'</td><tr></table>').click({param1: value.href}, setSourceToVideoPlayer);
            });
            function setSourceToVideoPlayer(event){
                alert(event.data.param1);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

and in HTML

```
<table id="dynamicTable" class="table-hover"></table>
```

Problem is, with this code, when I click on any of item in list I get alert with passed datafor all items, one-by-one, not only for clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code. I have given the only idea, it might be possible some syntax error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var inHTML = "";

$.ajax({
    url:        'http://some.some',
    dataType:   "json",
    success:    function(data){
        $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><th><h5 style="margin-left: 15px; margin-top: 15px;">' + "Events" + '</h5></th></tr>');
        $.each(data.videos, function(key, value){

            $("#dynamicTable").append('<table><tr><td class="aktivniItem backgroundIdKlupa_izbornik_td" data="' + value.href + '" style="color: white">'+ moment(value.time).format('DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') +'</td><tr></table>');
        });

    $(".aktivniItem").click(function (){
     alert($(this).attr("data"));
    });

    }
});
});
```

Comment: I have updated the click event. Please try with that.

Comment: i don't know where i make mistake, but with this `alert($(this).attr("data"));` constantly i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Comment: There is no error in alert($(this).attr("data")); line. I think you have mistaken in other line.

Comment: yes i know, but i try to validate code without alert here http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html and everything is ok

Comment: I have edited the answer and it is verified in esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can get this to work, for now, is with `event.stopImmediatePropagation();`

```
function setSourceToVideoPlayer(event){
            alert(event.data.param1);
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
```

Here is detail about [this](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/). If this is not a good way to do this, pls tell me. Thnx